# Splitting input into two with for-loop

Tags: python-3.x

This is where I got stuck, trying to learn Python using web-course.

> > Write a program that takes a single input line of the form «number1»+«number2», where both of these represent positive integers, and outputs the sum of the two numbers. For example on input 5+12 the output should be 17.

We shouldn't use split() or any import.

I think the solution is to use Character and its value of 43 and on that way substring but I am not sure. Only thing that I am sure is that solution is simple no fancy functions or imports needed.

Here is what i think might be close to solution

```
S = input()
for position in range(0,len(S):
      #code for substrings 5 to number1, and 12 to number2
result = int(number1)+int(number2)
print(result)
```

Comment: Can't you just use two raw_input() expressions?

Comment: No they are not covered by material we have read so far.

Comment: Related: [Python - Extracting a substring using a for loop instead of Split method or any other means](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18599398/python-extracting-a-substring-using-a-for-loop-instead-of-split-method-or-any)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`str.partition`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition):

```
line = raw_input()
num1, _, num2 = line.partition('+')
print(int(num1) + int(num2))
```

If you can't use `str.partition` and want to use a `for` loop, then `enumerate` should help:

```
for i, c in enumerate(line):
    if c == '+':
        # what goes here?
```

Comment: .. technically right, but if the OP isn't supposed to use `split()`, then I don't think using `partition()` is quite cricket.  Hard to say without seeing the unquoted part of the question that describes the rules, though, and the question title does seem to mention a for loop.

Comment: yeah we have to use for-loop and no partition() if it possibble to avoid

Comment: There is no unquated part of the question. In that course we haven't digged deeper into functions or imports. That course is very basic and all solutions should be as simple as possible.

Comment: I am gratefull on your wish to help, but I dont think that I can use enum() either. As question says split input string given in form (5+12) into two substrings number1=5, number2= 12 with help of for-loop. That is what i cant do alone. I can change then into integers and add them on my own.

Comment: @Aenohe instead of `enumerate` try `range(len(line))`.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer**

```
S = input()
for position in range(0, len(S)):
plus=S[position]
    if (plus!="+"):
      continue
    number1=int(S[0:position])
    number2=int(S[position+1:len(S)])
    print(number1+number2)
```