# Python - Extracting a substring using a for loop instead of Split method or any other means

Tags: python, string, for-loop, substring, extract

I'm taking an [online Python course](http://cscircles.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/8-remix/) which poses a problem where the programmer is to extract a substring using a for loop. There was a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12285240/splitting-input-into-two-with-for-loop) asked a year ago, but it didn't really get answered.

So the problem reads:

> Write a program that takes a single input line of the form «number1»+«number2», where both of these represent positive integers, and outputs the sum of the two numbers. For example on input 5+12 the output should be 17.

The first HINT given is

> Use a for loop to find the + in the string, then extract the substrings before and after the +.

This is my attempt, which I know is wrong because there is no position in the loop where it equals a '+'. How do I find the position where the '+' is in the string "5+12"?

```
S = input()
s_len = len(S)
for position in range (0,s_len):
   if position == '+':
      print(position[0,s_len])
```

**SPOILER ALERT - Edit to show any CSC Waterloo course takers the answer

```
S = input()
s_len = len(S)
for position in range (0,s_len):
   if S[position] == '+':
      number1 = int(S[0:position])
      number2 = int(S[position:s_len])
sum = number1 + number2
print(sum)
```

Comment: Martijn, Ashwini ended up providing a better answer to the original duplicate question. So wasn't this worth the repost? I say yes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `enumerate`, if you want to do this using a loop:

```
S = input()
for position, character in enumerate(S):
   if character == '+':
      print(position)
      break  # break out of the loop once the character is found
```

`enumerate` returns both index and the item from the iterable/iterator.

```
>>> list(enumerate("foobar"))
[(0, 'f'), (1, 'o'), (2, 'o'), (3, 'b'), (4, 'a'), (5, 'r')]
```

Working version of your solution:

```
S = input()
s_len = len(S)
for position in range(0, s_len):
   if S[position] == '+':        #use indexing to fetch items from the string.
      print(position)
```

Comment: Thanks Ashwini! I didn't think of assigning the position as an index to the string!